# Animate while UIScrollView bounces

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview

I want to do a little animation every time the UIScrollView bounces, to be exact, I want a button to move a little bit to the left and then back to it's original position. I use the `scrollViewDidScroll` method and check if the scrollView's contentOffset is higher than the actual content height and then call the animation. The problem is that the animation is called multiple times during the bounce if I do it like that. Is there a way to only call it once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an ivar or property named something like animationActive that will keep track of animation. When you start it, set `animationActive = YES;` and when animation completes, set `animationActive = NO;`. And of course, before you start animation, check `if (animationActive == YES)`.